# I am using generalised mixed effects models family = binomial to determine difference between disturbed and undistubed substrate

Tags: mixed-models, chi-squared

I am using a GLMM model to determine differences in soil compaction across 3 locations and 2 seasons in undisturbed and disturbed sites. I used location and seas as random effects. My teacher says to use the compaction reading divided by its upper bound as the Y value against the different sites (fixed effect). (I was previously using disturbed and undisturbed sites as 1,0 as Y against the compaction reading - so the opposite way around.) The random variables are minimal. I was using both `glmer` (`glmer` to determine AIC and therefore best model fit (but this cannot be done in `glmmPQL`)) while `glmmPQL` provides all amounts of variation which `glmer` does not. So while these outcomes are very similar when using disturbed and undisturbed as Y (as well as matching the graphs) only `glmmPQL` is similar to the graphs when using proportion of compaction reading. `glmer` using proportions is totally different. Additionally my teacher says I need to validate my model choice with a chi-squared value and if over-dispersed use a quasi binomial. But I cannot find any way to do this in `glmmPQL` and with `glmer` showing strange results using proportions as Y I am unsure if this is correct. I also cannot use quasi binomial in either `glmer` or `glmmPQL`.

My response was the compaction reading which is measured from 0 to 6 (kg per cm squared) inclusive. The explanatory variable was Type (diff soil either disturbed and not disturbed = 4 categories because some were artificially disturbed to pull out differences). All compaction readings were divided by 6 to make them a proportion and so a continuous variable bounded by 0 and 1 but  containing values of both 0 and 1. (I also tried the reverse and coded disturbed as 1 and undisturbed as 0 and compared these groups separately across all Types (due to 4 Types) and left compaction readings as original). Using  glmer with code:

```r
model1 <- glmer(comp/6 ~ Type  +(1|Loc/Seas), data=mydata, 
              family = "binomial")
model2 <- glmer(comp/6~Type +(1|Loc) , data=mydata, family="binomial")
```

and using glmmPQL:

```r
mod1 <-glmmPQL(comp/6~Type, random=~1|Loc, family = binomial, data=mydata)
mod2 <- glmmPQL(comp/6~Type, random=~1|Loc/Seas, family = binomial, data=mydata)
```

I could compare models in `glmer` but not in `glmmPQL` but the latter gave me the variance for all random effects plus residual variance whereas `glmer` did not provide the residual variance (so was left wondering what was the total amount and what proportion were these random effects responsible for)
When I used `glmer` this way, the results were completely different to `glmmPQL` as in no there was no sig difference at all in `glmer` but very much a sig diff in `glmmPQL`. (However if I do the reverse and code by disturbed and undisturbed these do provide similar results between `glmer` and `glmmPQL` and what is  suggested by the graphs - but my supervisor said this is not strictly correct (eg: `mod3 <- glmmPQL(Status~compaction, random=~1|Loc/Seas, family = binomial, data=mydata)` where Status is 1 or 0 according to disturbed or undisturbed)  plus my supervisor would like me to provide a chi squared goodness of fit for the model chosen - so can only use `glmer` here ?). Additionally, the random effects variance is minimal, and glmer model choice removes these as non significant (although keeping one in provides a smaller AIC). Removing them (as suggested by the chi-squared test (but not AIC) and running as only a glm is consistent to both results from glmmPQL and what is observed on the graph. Sorry if this seems very pedantic, but I am trying to do what is correct for my supervisor and  for the species I am researching. I know there are differences.. they are seen, observed, eyeballing the data suggests so and so do the graphs.. Maybe I should just run the glm ? Thank you for answering me. I will find some output to post.

Comment: You should probably re-post this on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but there are some things you could do to improve your question: (1) more detail on your response variable. Is it binary (0/1), a discrete ratio (e.g. 0/10, 1/21, 2/10), or a continuous variable bounded by 0 and 1? If it is continuous, does your data contain responses that are exactly 0 or 1? (2) Could you post (as text, not as images) the code lines for fitting the models and the output of `summary()` for each model? (3) Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "provides all amounts of variation" ?

Comment: Ben Bolker  I have answered in an edit above as there are not enough characters here to do so. Hope that is ok. I am new to this page.

Comment: Your edits are good, but this definitely belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). In the meantime try adding `weights = rep(6, nrow = mydata)` to your `glmer` call (did you get warnings about non-integer response values???

Comment: Thank you so much Ben Bolker. I wondered how to put in a weights component, and tried with just weights = 6 but i can see now that was wrong -so thank you very much - I will definitely give that a go. I also wrote to a stats tutor at my Uni and they suggested using glmmTMB - which does provide me with a model comparison and also can pull out differences using emmeans. Thank you again.